# Using a method in a service in angular does not seem to work

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

For some reason, there is a method that does not seem to work on my service. What I originally want to do is retrieve Params and get the particular parameter to fetch the server. (I'm not using real servers, this is just a dummy example). Here's my code.

Server TS:

```js
export class ServerComponent implements OnInit {
  // The varable id is for capturing the service we want.
  server: {id: number, name: string, status: string};
  id: number

  // I will show serversService
  constructor(private serversService: ServersService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // When I console.log the id, it gives me the correct id.
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = params['id']
      console.log(this.id)
    })
    // Yet, when I console.log the server, it gives me undefined. 
    this.server = this.serversService.getServer(this.id);
    console.log(this.server)
  }

}
```

Server Template:

```html
<h5>{{ server.name }}</h5>
<p>Server status is {{ server.status }}</p>
```

Server Service:

```js
private servers = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Productionserver',
      status: 'online'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Testserver',
      status: 'offline'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Devserver',
      status: 'offline'
    }
  ];

  getServer(id: number) {
    const server = this.servers.find(
      s => {
        return s.id === id;
      }
    );
    return server;
  }
```

AppModule:

```js
  {
    path: 'servers/:id',
    component: ServerComponent
  }
```

The server template does not show because `server` is undefined. Now `server` is undefined because `this.serversService.getServer(this.id)` does not work. It does work, however, when I hardcode a number as the `getServer(id)` parameter. Is this perhaps because `this.id` gets defined after `this.serversService.getServer(this.id)` is executed? If so, how will I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
this.server = this.serversService.getServer(this.id);
```

is executed before subscription is processed.

Try:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  this.id = params['id']
  console.log(this.id)
  this.server = this.serversService.getServer(this.id);
  console.log(this.server)
})
```

Comment: For some reason, it still doesn't work. If you have any other methods, that would be great. If not, thanks anyways!

Comment: @Razel, I got the error. `params['id']` is actually a string, and in the service, the ids are numbers.